# C++ opencv image editing

Tags: opencv

I want to provide center coordinates of small square i.e (5,5)[small square is 10x10] to be placed on (8,8) coordinates of  larger square of 20x20.
to get this image result:

Comment: do you want to place an image or draw a rectangle?

Comment: Post code. What have you actually done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, I didn't test it though, so please comment if it doesn't work and I'll try to fix it =)

```
cv::Mat placeImageInImage(cv::Point center, cv::Mat src, cv::Mat dst_orig)
{
    cv::Mat dst = dst_orig.clone();

    cv::Rect targetRect = cv::Rect(center.x-src.cols/2, center.y-src.rows/2, src.cols, src.rows);

    cv::Rect srcRect = cv::Rect(0,0,src.cols, src.rows);
    cv::Rect dstRect = cv::Rect(0,0,dst.cols, dst.rows);

    cv::Rect roi = targetRect & dstRect;

    srcRect.width = roi.width;
    srcRect.height = roi.height;

    // didnt test, maybe swap the order:
    srcRect.x += roi.x - targetRect.x;
    srcRect.y += roi.y - targetRect.y;

    src(srcRect).copyTo(dst(roi));

    return dst;
}
```

using this code to test:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");

    cv::Mat input2;
    cv::resize(input, input2, cv::Size(256, 256));

    cv::Mat result = placeImageInImage(cv::Point(256, 256), input2, input);

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("result", result);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

[image]

Comment: what if i want to mention some particular coordinates of smaller image say (20, 25) to be placed on bigger image.

Comment: you mean a subimage? And place position anchor will be the center of the subimage?

Comment: no place  position anchor could be any coordinates of the subimage

Comment: and where inside of the bigger image should it be placed?!?

Comment: i figured it out. now stuck at loading PNGs. unable to load alpha channel. i tried IMREAD_UNCHANGED but giving an error. what should i do?

Comment: try imread(path, -1); doc says to use negative value if alpha channel is needed

Comment: i tried it already it's giving an error :- OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype)) in cv::Mat::copyTo

Comment: does both of the images (source and destination) have an alpha channel? If not, you'll have to convert them with cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2BGRA) before calling the function.

Comment: but please keep in mind that copying images with alpha channels to other images might not be what you want to do. it will completely overwrite the part of the destination image, even if the alpha value of source is zero in that pixel! If that's a problem you probably need some kind of alpha blending instead of copyTo!

Comment: i have already written a code for alpha blending but kind of stuck at this centre coordinate thing. do you have any link to "cv::Rect" documentation with better explanation written then  OPENCV.ORG

Comment: cv::Rect is just top-left's x y and width height so if you know width and height (= (sub)image's cols and rows) then centre at some coordinate means to place x= coordinate.x - width/2 and y = coordinate.y - height/2